# Django | ForeignKey a Self pero añadiendo un filter

Tags: django

Se que es posible hacer un foreignkey a self (al mismo modelo). Claro que además de ello me interesaría que hiciera un filter para no tener que seleccionar entre todas, sino entre las de un area_installation concreta. ¿Es posible?

Supongamos que el modelo es Installation y queremos que comunication_point haga a "self", pero en vez de mostrar todos los resultados, queramos filtrar por una area_installation concreta.

¿Sería posible algo así?

**Models.py**

```
class Installation(models.Model):
    area_installation = models.ForeignKey(AreaInstallation, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    comunication_point =  models.ForeignKey ('self', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, related_name="comunications_p" ).filter(area_installation="Abastecimiento")
```

Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Qué ocurre cuando no hay ningún `comunication_port`? ¿Cómo prevees añadirlos?

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres limitar los valores de una clave foránea puedes utilizar `ForeignKey.limit_choices_to` como explica la documentación [ForeignKey.limit_choices_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to).